# Getting the error floating point exception: 8

Tags: c++

I have no idea why g++ doesn't like my code. It ran fine in java. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(long number);

int main(){
const long number = 600851475143;
long max = 0;
for(long i= 0; i*i <= number; i++)
    if(number % i == 0 && isPrime(i))
        max = i;
cout<< max << endl;

return 0;
}

bool isPrime(long number){
if(number <= 1) return false;
if(number == 2) return true;
if(number % 2 == 0) return false;

for(long     i= 3; i*i <= number; i+=2)
    if(number % i == 0)
        return false;
return true;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note for future use, that I was also getting the same error when I was (very rarely) dividing by 0.

Comment: That actually was the problem although it was with % not /. Same idea though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
const long number = 600851475143;
```

There is overflow, long can't hold that big number.

see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
LONG_MAX is 2147483647
```

try:

```
const unsigned long long number = 600851475143;
unsigned long longmax = 0;
```

Edit:

You can't % against 0, `i` starts from `0`

```
for(long i= 0; i*i <= number; i++)
           ^^
{
    if(number % i == 0 && isPrime(i))
               ^^^
{
   max = i;
   cout<< max << endl;
}
```

}

Minor change to a working version:

```
bool isPrime(unsigned long long  number);

int main(){

    const unsigned long long number = 600851475143;
    unsigned long long max = 0;
    for(long i = 1; i*i <= number; i++)
    {
        if(number % i == 0 && isPrime(i))
        {
            max = i;
            cout<< max << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(unsigned long long  number)
{
    if(number <= 1) return false;
    if(number == 2) return true;
    if(number % 2 == 0) return false;

    for(unsigned long long i= 3; i*i <= number; i+=2)
    {
        if(number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @JoshHorowitz what error? There is literally no floating point anywhere.

Comment: Ah you're doing a modulus against zero.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a floating point anywhere, but if I had to guess it's because it's due to overflow. Use `unsigned long long` or `long long` instead of regular `long`.

`sizeof(long)` on some compilers has evaluated to 4, similar to `sizeof(int)`, which means that the limit of `long` is 2147483647. `long long` is required by the C++ standard to be at least 64-bits, double that of `long` and `int`, which has a signed maximum of 9223372036854775807.

The error stems from your code:
You're doing modulus by zero, which is wrong.

Consider doing this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(unsigned long long number);

int main(){
    const unsigned long long number = 600851475143;
    unsigned long long max = 0;
    for(unsigned long long i= 1; i*i <= number; i++)
        if(number % i == 0 && isPrime(i))
            max = i;
    cout<< max << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(unsigned long long number) {
    if(number <= 1) return false;
    if(number == 2) return true;
    if(number % 2 == 0) return false;

    for(unsigned long long i= 3; i*i <= number; i+=2)
        if(number % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Notice how `i = 0` was changed to `i = 1`

Answer (score 0):

For me, this bug came up when checking for integer overflow when doing a product:

```
#define INT_MIN -2147483648 // -2^31
#define INT_MAX  2147483647 //  2^31-1

int out=-1, x=-5;

if ((out > 0 && (x > INT_MAX/out || x < INT_MIN/out)) ||
    (out < 0 && (x < INT_MAX/out || x > INT_MIN/out))) {
  // what to do for overflow
} else {
  out *= x;
}
```

The issue is that because `abs(INT_MIN) > abs(INT_MAX)`, exactly when `out=-1`, the condition `INT_MIN/out` was causing an overflow of `int` (because of `0`, there's not enough room to fit `INT_MAX+1` in `int`). I added a new condition to fix the floating point issue: `out == -1 && (x > INT_MAX || x <= INT_MIN)`